# Is Domain entity validation in entity class a proper way?

Tags: c#, validation, domain-driven-design, entity

I am new ad domain driven design and have questions about entity objects.
The objects should not move only data like following. I am using c# programming language.

```
public class Job 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

it should some logic like:

```
public class Job 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    
    public bool IsActive() { .... }
    
    public bool IsAppliable() { .... }
    
}
```

But where can I validate the data property validations? Is it in entity class like this?
(Maybe using getter setter properties for validations instead of using Validate() method)

```
public class Job 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    
    public bool IsActive() { .... }
    
    public bool IsAppliable() { .... }
    
    public List<string> Validate(){
        List<string> validationErrors = new List<string> ();
        
        if(Title.Length < 3)
            validationErrors.Add("Title should be minimum 3 characters")
        
        if(Title.Length > 300)
            validationErrors.Add("Title should be max 300 characters")
        
        ....
    }
    
}
```

Or should create a new generic class For Validate the Entity using 3rd party tools like FluentValidation? Which is the proper way for domain driven design?

Comment: See [Validation and DDD](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/validation-and-ddd/) Validation and DDD can be a tricky combination. How to perform validation in a way that doesn’t lead to domain knowledge leakage?

Comment: Don't you public setters or you will end up with a anemic domain model. Try to change the state of the aggregate root through operations that enable the business operations you are trying to implement.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: if your concern is proofreading data entry, the domain model is not the ideal place for that logic.

---

Isolated data validations normally belong somewhere outside of the entities (motivation: separation of responsibilities).

If we have some general purpose data structure like a String, and we want to make sure that String also satisfies a bunch of additional constraints, then normally the tool we use to achieve that is a [parser](https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2019/11/05/parse-don-t-validate/).

> a parser is just a function that consumes less-structured input and produces more-structured output. -- [Alexis King](https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2019/11/05/parse-don-t-validate/)

Parsing is not normally a domain entity concern; I would expect to see it somewhere near the presentation layer.  For example, if we are trying to validate information from a web form, the parsing would normally happen up near the controller.

A common design choice is to use a type to represent the parsed form of the value - after verifying that the general purpose data structure satisfies our constraints, we wrap that data structure in a type (aka a "value object") that promises those constraints have been satisfied.  Domain entity code interacts with the type, not the underlying data structure.

We parse for more complicated data structures too -- for example, the logic that takes in an HTTP request entity, and works the entire problem (is the entity an x-www-form-urlencoded document? does it satisfy the constraints we have defined for the keys? do each of the values satisfy their own constraints?) is a parser.

The logic of domain entities is normally about policy, not validation.  I normally consider a state machine metaphor here: the domain model defines how you transition from one state to another; it's not responsible for which states are valid, but instead for which states are *reachable*.

---

That all said, no one is giving away prizes for "most DDD design".  The "design rules" are an opinion on patterns that will make the lives of development teams easier.  But if those rules don't work in your context, then you shouldn't use them.